# Android LiveData/StateFlow List Item Property Update Issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

So I'm updating my `RecylerView` with `StateFlow<List>` like following:

**My data class:**

```
data class Student(val name: String, var isSelected: Boolean)
```

**My ViewModel logic:**

```
fun updateStudentsOnSelectionChanged(targetStudent: Student) {
    val targetIndex = _students.value.indexOf(targetStudent)
    val isSelected = !targetStudent.isSelected

    _students.value[targetIndex].isSelected = isSelected        //<- doesn't work
}
```

**Problem:** The UI is not changed, but the `isSelected` inside `_student` is changed, what's going on? (same to `LiveData`)

Comment: It’s difficult to get proper behavior out of StateFlow or RecyclerView if you are using mutable classes or collections, because they have no way to detect changes between old and new when old and new are the same instance.

Comment: You should check updating function in fragment/activity. It may not call. If it call to check a new value.

Answer (score 2):

I assume `_students` is a `StateFlow<List>`. Changing the `isSelected` property of the `Student` model doesn't trigger the `StateFlow`. The workaround would be to make the `isSelected` property of the `Student` data class immutable to get it compared when new state is set, create a `MutableList` out of the current list and copy the existing `Student` object with the new value for `isSelected` property:

```
data class Student(val name: String, val isSelected: Boolean)

val students = _students.value.toMutableList()
students[targetIndex] = students[targetIndex].copy(isSelected = isSelected)
_students.value = students
```

Comment: This won’t work because StateFlow doesn’t emit duplicate consecutive items. Since you’re passing the same list instance back to it, it will see it as the same item.

Comment: Thanks for noticing @Tenfour04, you are right, I was relying that changing the `var isSelected: Boolean` will cause the flow to trigger, but it didn't happen I think because `isSelected` property is a mutable and it doesn't get compared in `equals` method. I've added a workaround.

Comment: The mutable property does get compared, but it’s being compared to itself since the same instance is being pointed at. Both the list and the item in the list have to be changed to new instances for the comparison to detect a change (as your code does now), because otherwise the old and new values are the same instances.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, thanks to @Tenfour04 and @Sergey, I finally found out that `StateFlow/LiveData` cannot detect the internal changes, that's because they are both actually **comparing the Reference** of the `.value`.

That means, If I want to force the `StateFow<List>` to update, the only way is to assign a new `List` to it, therefore I created the following helper extension function:

```
fun <T> List<T>.mapButReplace(targetItem: T, newItem: T) = map {
    if (it == targetItem) {
        newItem
    } else {
        it
    }
}

//this function returns a new List with the content I wanted
```

In `Fragment`:

```
val itemCheckAction: (Student) -> Unit = { student ->
    val newStudent = student.copy(isSelected = !student.isSelected)    //prepare a new Student

    viewModel.updateStudentsOnSelectionChanged(student, newStudent)    //update the StateFlow
}
```

In `ViewModel`:

```
fun updateStudentsOnSelectionChanged(currentStudent: Student, newStudent: Student) {
    val newList = _students.value.mapButReplace(currentStudent, newStudent)

    _students.value = newList       //assign a new List with different reference
}
```