# Kotlin - StateFlow not emitting updates to its collectors

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I got a StateFlow of type UserStateModel (data class) in my app.

```
private val _userStateFlow: MutableStateFlow<UserStateModel?> = MutableStateFlow(UserStateModel())
val userStateFlow: StateFlow<UserStateModel?> = _userStateFlow
```

here is the UserStateModel

```
data class UserStateModel(
    val uid: String? = null,
    val username: String? = null,
    val profileImageUrl: String? = null,
    var isLoggedIn: Boolean = false,
    val isPremiumUser: Boolean = false,
    val posts: List<Post>? = listOf()
)
```

When I update the StateFlow with a new Username it emits the change to the collectors and the UI updates.
But when I change a property inside the posts: List? list it doesnt emit the changes.
When I change the size of the list it does, when I change the name property of the Post at index 0 it doesnt.
How can I detect changes to the child properties of the Data class?

Right now I use an ugly workaround, I add

```
val updateErrorWorkaround: Int = 0
```

to the UserStateModel data class and increase it by one so the collectors get notified

P.s I'm using MVVM + Clean Architecture and Jeptack Compose

**EDIT**
Thats my Post Model:

```
data class Post(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String, 
    val tags: MutableList<Tag>? = null

)
```

Here is how I update the MutableList:

```
val posts = userStateFlow.value?.posts
posts.get(index).tags?.add(myNewTag)
_userStateFlow.value = userStateFlow.value?.copy(posts = posts)
```

Those changes are not emitted to the collectors

Comment: How is `Post` defined? Is it also a data class? Also, how do you update the StateFlow? Do you re-use the same objects that you provided earlier or each time you create an entirely separate copy of the data?

Comment: Hey @broot, thanks for trying to help. I updated my question with your requested details

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71187022/3466808.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`StateFlow` emits only if it detects changes to the value, it ignores replacing the value with the same data. To do this, it compares the previous value with the new one. For this reason, we shouldn't modify the data that we already provided to the `StateFlow`, because it won't be able to detect changes.

For example, we set `value` to a `User(name=John)`. Then we mutate the same user object by modifying its `name` to `James` and we set the `value` to this "new" user object. `StateFlow` compares "new" `User(name=James)` with its stored value, which is now also `User(name=James)`, so it doesn't see any changes.

In your example you created a copy of `UserStateModel`, but inside you re-use the same objects and you mutate them. In this case you added a new item to `tags` and this change affected old `UserStateModel` as well, so `StateFlow` doesn't detect the change.

To fix the problem, you need to copy all the data that was changed and do not mutate anything in-place. It is safer to make all the data immutable, so `val` and `List` - this way you are forced to make copies. I changed `tags` to `val tags: List<Tag> = listOf()`, then your code could look like the following:

```kotlin
val posts = userStateFlow.value?.posts!!.toMutableList()
posts[index] = posts[index].copy(tags = posts[index].tags + myNewTag)
userStateFlow.value = userStateFlow.value?.copy(posts = posts)
```

Here we create a copy of not only `UserStateModel`. We also copy `posts` list, the `Post` that we modify and we also copy the list of tags.

Alternatively, if this behavior of `StateFlow` is more annoying to you than helpful, you can use `SharedFlow` which doesn't compare values, but just emits.

Comment: This is the most detailed and helpful answer I've ever got on a question. Thank you so much!

Comment: Even when I pass a random string into my StateFlow event, the receiver never collects...

Comment: This is really right answer!

Comment: for tag, u can generate random id using UUID.randomUUID().toString() :)